# Getting Weird Behavior while Parsing the XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, xmlstreamreader

My Application is behaving weird While parsing the Well Formed xml file for some elements. It is throwing parsing exception even if file is having well formed data.  I checked the xml file and it has proper end tag at the line number reported in the exception. I also checked the parent element and sibling elements too and they also seemed correct to me having proper end tags.

**Details:**

1. Application is using Streaming API for XML.
2. Reading of xml file is being done in batches i.e. A set of elements are being read at a time.
3. **Exception is being thrown for particular elements and if we remove those element it runs fine and proceed to parse remaining set of data.**

**Snapshot of the exception:**

```
<strong>ERROR 281114.014425 - Error parsing XML
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1489299,35]
Message: The element type "float" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</float>".
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLReaderImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(Unknown Source)**
        at com.iii.xmlharvest.feed.XmlFeedProcessor.readDocuments(XmlFeedProcessor.java:356)
```

Comment: can you share the xml?

Comment: Indeed, a short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help. I generally trust parsers to report errors correctly...

Comment: can't share the xml but its well formed i have checked it manually.

Comment: Hi Jon,
XMLEventWriter eventWriter=xmlOutputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(outputStream);
int counter = 0;
while (eventReader.hasNext() && !limitReached) {
try{
XMLEvent xmlEvent = eventReader.nextEvent();
if (xmlEvent.isStartElement()) {
StartElement startElement = xmlEvent.asStartElement();
if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals(docStartTagName)) {
if(counter==0)
docStartLine = startElement.getLocation().getLineNumber();
readingDoc = true;
}
}
}

Comment: Hi Jon,
can't share the whole program sorry.
it throws exception at 
XMLEvent xmlEvent = eventReader.nextEvent();